# php round a number

Tags: php, variables, rounding

I have a variable

```
$amount = 621.00;
```

I need the 30% of the variable with output 186.30

When I calculate:

```
$amount2 = round($amount*30/100 , 2);

echo $amount2
```

gives the output of 186.3

how can I have output 186.30

Comment: Look into [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Simply said: "How to output a floating point number with a fixed number of decimals after the point". There is no rounding involved, or you must explain which one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number_format()` should do the trick.

```
// english notation without thousands separator
$amount2 = number_format($amount2, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) for that:

```
$amount2 = number_format($amount * 30 / 100, 2);
echo $amount2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number_format`

For example `number_format($amount2, 2)`

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

use `number_format($amount2,2)` at the end.

See documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php